# Do M-Audio MIDI controllers (Axiom, Oxygen, etc.) work with OS X Yosemite?

Tags: midi, osx, controller, m-audio

If so, which ones, and with which software?

Drivers for Yosemite have so far not been released by M-Audio, but I assume some controllers will work in any case. (I am considering buying the Axiom 61.)

(Note: I am aware that discussion of Yosemite is pedantically blacklisted on the Apple StackExchange; I'm sure people here are more open-minded, particularly since the question will continue to be relevant after a public release.)

Comment: This may be off-topic here as it is really a hardware and software support question for features of an operating system.  It is tech support that isn't even directly related to audio.  It is also a fair bit list oriented if the answer isn't simply "yes" or "no" for all of them.  I'll leave it for now since I'm not familiar enough with the topic, but I wouldn't be surprised if this gets closed in its current form.

Comment: Fair enough. Would you recommend another StackExchange site?

Comment: Not sure, Apple.SE would have been the most logical, maybe SuperUser, possibly even here if you can clean up the question some.  List oriented questions tend to not do well anywhere on SE though.  Removing the list and just asking if any of them work on platform X is probably workable on SU though.

Comment: Well, my Radium49 keyboard isn't recognized anymore now i've installed Yosemite :-(

Comment: I just upgraded, and my old MidiMan Midisport 4x4 doesn't work anymore! But my Steinberg UR28M audio interface works fine. MD

Comment: Yep my AxiomPro49 doesn't seem to be working. It does not input any data to Logic. My Scarlett 2i2 interface works fine, though.

Answer (score 1):

USB MIDI devices work with any OS if they are "class compliant".

This [is true for the Axiom 61](http://www.m-audio.com/products/view/axiom-61), as well for almost all other USB MIDI devices.

Answer (score 1):

My M-Audio Mobile Pre-USB is not recognized my Yosemite; I can get it to work by unplugging the usb cable and re-plugging it in but it's gone after the next restart.
Cant find any updated drivers (yet). Strange behavior and inconvenient but it is a work around.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Axiom 61 (first edition) with Yosemite and its working fine. As stated above, its class compliant.